# Hashmap inside Hashmap javascript html5

Tags: javascript, html, hashmap

Problem: adding **Hashmap inside another Hashmap in HTML5**.
The firstly created Hashmap doesn't seem able to accept, inside itself, another Hashmap defined neither as a Key nor as a value. I declared the 2nd Hashmap independently and then tried using "connect" (console points undefined error) and even tried attributing to the key of 1st Hashmap the name of the 2nd Hashmap. The problem doesn't seem to be the number of values (the implemented hashmap accepted as much values as I entered).
There is no implementation pre-defined in HTML5 such as in JAVA (with a "put" command) to connect Hashmaps, so I am pretty clueless what else to try (newbie, searched intensively but did not found anything so direct to HTML5). 
Also, there are a few others Hashmaps to be included inside the 1st. 
Thanks in advance

```
var Hz125={}; //(1st Hashmap)
var dbHL90={}; // (2nd Hashmap)

dbHL90 = x in Hz125; //No compiling errors, 
            //but it doesn't seem to be included inside the 1st Hashmap.
dbHL90['right'] = {realFreq:'123', realLoudness: ''};
dbHL90['left']= {realFreq:'121', realLoudness: ''};
```

Comment: Check documentation on `in` operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set one Hashmap (actually an object) inside another object as value:

```
var Hz125={}; //(1st Hashmap)
var dbHL90={}; // (2nd Hashmap)

Hz125['x'] = dbHL90;
```

or

```
Hz125.x = dbHL90;
```

You can't set object as a key (I think that ES6 have weakmap that allow to do this).